# Arrange 3d objects in a circle shape

Tags: c++

I am using c++ and g3d to draw a simple sphere, but dont know how to arrange multiple objects/spheres in a circular shape.

```
for(i = 0.0f;i<1.4f;i+=0.2f){ 
    sphere->position = (Vector3(2,i,0));
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I didn't notice the formatting got messed up when I posted it, the code is fixed and more legible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// num_points is the number of points/objects in 
// the circle and coords is just the center location of where to draw
static void draw_circle_loop(float radius, int num_points, struct vector2d *coords)
{
    int i;
    float x, y;
    float angle;

    for (i = 0; i < num_points; i++)
    {
        angle = i * (2.0f * M_PI / num_points);
        x = coords->x + cosf(angle) * radius;
        y = coords->y + sinf(angle) * radius;
        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }
     glVertex2f(coords->x + radius, coords->y);
}
```

Try something like this. Instead of calling `glVertex2f` use those coordinates to place things circularly.